# How to redirect Url that has %E2%80%8C code

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a few Urls on my site that have "%E2%80%8C" in them which I want to redirect to their specific pages.

For Example: https://suntrics.com/tag/features%E2%80%8C-%E2%80%8Cof%E2%80%8C-%E2%80%8Ca-%E2%80%8Chealthy%E2%80%8C-%E2%80%8Cwork%E2%80%8C-%E2%80%8Cenvironment%E2%80%8C/

Want to redirect to: https://suntrics.com/tag/features-of-a-healthy-work-environment/

I have tried this code on my .htaccess.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^/]+)/.*?[&%] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]

It is working but it's redirecting to my homepage and not to the page which I want. Also, this code creating problem when I create a new post in the wordpress so I had to remove it.

So could you guys please help me to fix this?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to fix your site to not have nonsense unicode characters in the links?

Comment: @TZHX well that's also an option but how do I do that? I am not into much coding.

Comment: @AlfredAllen Try out the below solution.

Comment: @KrunalBhimajiyani Yes, it's perfectly working now. Thank you so much and God bless you, bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using the [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook.

Try out this code in your functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_custom_url' );

function redirect_custom_url() {
    $uri      = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $protocol = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
    $crt_url  = $protocol . '://' . $host . $uri;

    $pattern  = '(%E2%80%8C|%e2%80%8c)';

    if ( preg_match( $pattern, $crt_url ) === 1 ) {
        $redirect_url = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $crt_url );
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This code is working for the above URL but it's not working for the below ones. 

https://suntrics.com/tag/fun%e2%80%8c-%e2%80%8coutdoor%e2%80%8c-%e2%80%8cactivities/
https://suntrics.com/tag/sox%e2%80%8c-compliance/
https://suntrics.com/tag/what%e2%80%8c-is%e2%80%8c-sox%e2%80%8c-compliance/

Although it's the same, except it's in small letters. so could you please help me to fix this too??

Comment: Please check my updated answer and let me know if it's working or not.